# get / detect date and time of when div element content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How could I get the date / time of when the `"DOMSubtreeModified"` / or when my dynamic div element has changed. Basically whenever my div element's content changes, I would simply like to print a time stamp of `time` & `mo/day/year`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified any issues with this one?

Comment: Oh, wow that's terrific, but I don't want that in the title bar. But let me try that logic

Comment: You might note that [*DOMSubtreeModified* is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) so you can expect it to be removed or replaced in some future specification or standard. It's also buggy in IE 9 and missing from Opera.

Comment: Ah, thanks is there a suggested alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) event listener to the element.

```
var element = document.getElementById('foo');

element.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

  console.log(time); // 7:01:21 PM
  console.log(formattedDate); // 3/15/2016
}, false);

// change something on element
setTimeout(function() {
  element.dataset.foo = 'bar';
}, 3000);
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n1mmdayk/3/**

Comment: Thanks, this looks great however it looks like it's failing with changing to get by class name. There is an error being caught on element.addEventListener. https://jsfiddle.net/n1mmdayk/5/

Comment: @MattDamon use `querySelector` https://jsfiddle.net/n1mmdayk/6/ otherwise `getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you'd have to iterate through each element like this https://jsfiddle.net/n1mmdayk/9/. There's other ways of binding events such as using event delegation

Comment: Thanks for the info | your set time out function is not working on test